# Django : Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I have problem when I want to use simple CreateView for creating new user. Everything is ok, I can create user, but when I want logging with new created user, I cant do it.

### I got this type of my password in admin:

**Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.**

Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using this form.

This is my code:

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager


    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        """app setting of user"""
        url = models.URLField(u'Site URL', max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)

    admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from models import CustomUser
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^create_user/$',(CreateView.as_view(model=CustomUser,       get_success_url =lambda: reverse('create_user'),
                                                                             template_name="create_user.html")), name='create_user'),
                   )
```

**create_user.html**

```
<div title="Create Form " id="/create_user">
        <p> <b>Create account:</b> </p>            
        {{ form.errors }}
    <form action="" method="post" id="id_create_user" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create account" style="">
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

And after creating user, I have to log in  as admin and change this password, and after that everything will be ok.[image: Example of my problem]

What should I do to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that CreateView is generating a form automatically based on the model, which means it's writing directly to the password field rather than using the correct API for creating a user.

Try this form instead, it'll handle it for you:

`from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^create_user/$',(CreateView.as_view(model=CustomUser, get_success_url =lambda: reverse('create_user'), form_class=UserCreationForm, template_name="create_user.html")), name='create_user'),
)
```

These forms essentially give you the same as what you see in the admin, which is a good starting point, if you're using a custom user model you might want to do some additional work to get your customisations in.

Here's the source code for the supplied UserCreationForm: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L61-L110

You can re-implement it yourself as a normal ModelForm, the key thing you must include is the save method where `user.set_password` is called.

Comment: It's work, but in template, I displayed just three fields, pass, re-pass, and username.. but i want to displayed all my fields.

Comment: Added some stuff to the end of the answer that should point you in the right direction